# Scraping table information

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I would like to extract the odds information from the website http://www.footballlocks.com/nfl_odds.shtml using Python.

I have been trying to do it with BeautifulSoup.

The optimal result would be to obtain the odds information in dictionary or list format, as the values will be fed into a mathematical formula.

the HTML code for the odds information is:

```
    <TABLE COLS="6" WIDTH="650" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="5" CELLPADDING="2">

  <TR>
    <TD WIDTH="19%"><span title="Date and Time of Game."><B>Date & Time</B></span></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="21%"><span title="Team Spotting Points in a Bet Against the Point Spread."><B>Favorite</B></span></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="14%"><span title="Short for Point Spread. Number of Points Subtracted from Final Score of Favorite to Determine Winner of a Point Spread Based Wager."><B>Spread</B></span></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="21%"><span title="Team Receiving Points in a Bet With the Point Spread."><B>Underdog</B></span></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="6%"><span title="Line for Betting Over or Under the Total number of Points Scored by Both Teams Combined. Synonymous With Over/Under."><B>Total</B></span></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="19%"><span title="Money odds to Win the Game Outright, Without any Point Spread. 
Minus (-) is Amount Bettors Risk for Each $100 on the Favorite to Win the Game Outright.
Plus (+) is Amount Bettors Win for Each $100 Risked on the Underdog to Win the Game Outright."><B>Money Odds</B></span></TD>
  </TR>






 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Detroit</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-6</TD>
    <TD>Tennessee</TD>
    <TD>47</TD>
    <TD>-$255 +$215</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Houston</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-2.5</TD>
    <TD>Kansas City</TD>
    <TD>43</TD>
    <TD>-$140 +$120</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At New England</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-6.5</TD>
    <TD>Miami</TD>
    <TD>42</TD>
    <TD>-$290 +$240</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>Baltimore</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-6.5</TD>
    <TD>At Cleveland</TD>
    <TD>42.5</TD>
    <TD>-$300 +$250</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Pittsburgh</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-3.5</TD>
    <TD>Cincinnati</TD>
    <TD>48.5</TD>
    <TD>-$180 +$160</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Washington</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-2.5</TD>
    <TD>Dallas</TD>
    <TD>45.5</TD>
    <TD>-$145 +$125</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At NY Giants</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-4.5</TD>
    <TD>New Orleans</TD>
    <TD>53.5</TD>
    <TD>-$225 +$185</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 1:00 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Carolina</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-13.5</TD>
    <TD>San Francisco</TD>
    <TD>45</TD>
    <TD>-$900 +$600</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 4:05 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Arizona</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-7</TD>
    <TD>Tampa Bay</TD>
    <TD>50</TD>
    <TD>-$310 +$260</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 4:05 ET</TD>
    <TD>Seattle</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-6.5</TD>
    <TD>At Los Angeles</TD>
    <TD>38</TD>
    <TD>-$290 +$240</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 4:25 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Denver</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-6.5</TD>
    <TD>Indianapolis</TD>
    <TD>46.5</TD>
    <TD>-$280 +$240</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 4:25 ET</TD>
    <TD>At Oakland</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-4.5</TD>
    <TD>Atlanta</TD>
    <TD>49</TD>
    <TD>-$210 +$180</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 4:25 ET</TD>
    <TD>At San Diego</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-3</TD>
    <TD>Jacksonville</TD>
    <TD>47</TD>
    <TD>-$165 +$145</TD>
  </TR>


 <TR>
    <TD>9/18 8:30 ET</TD>
    <TD>Green Bay</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-2.5</TD>
    <TD>At Minnesota</TD>
    <TD>43.5</TD>
    <TD>-$140 +$120</TD>
  </TR>




</TABLE>
```

The Python code thus far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = "http://www.footballlocks.com/nfl_odds.shtml"
html = urllib.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for record in soup.find_all('tr'):
  for data in record.find_all('td'):
    print data.text
```

PS. My background is economics and my programming experience is limited.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How would I get only the information pertaining to odds into a dictionary. For example 

9/18 1:00 ET At Carolina    -13.5 San Francisco 45 -$900 +$600

Would be:

 { 'At Carolina' : - 900 , 'San Francisco' : +600

Comment: You may want to edit your question to add the "this is my question" stuff above.

Comment: Indeed—you need to [edit] your question and specify better (exactly?) what the information is you're trying to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the nicest html to parse as there are no classes we can use but this will put all the rows into a list of dicts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "http://www.footballlocks.com/nfl_odds.shtml"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

# Use the text of one of the headers to find the correct table
table = soup.find("span", text="Date & Time").find_previous("table")



data = []
# start from second tr 
for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
    # index to get the tds we need
    tds = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]
    fav, under, odds = tds[1], tds[2], tds[-1]
    # split money odds into fav/under odds
    f_odds,u_odds = odds.split()

    data.append({fav: f_odds.replace(u"$", ""), under : u_odds.replace(u"$", "")})
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

Output:

```
[{u'At Detroit': u'-255', u'Tennessee': u'+215'},
 {u'At Houston': u'-130', u'Kansas City': u'+110'},
 {u'At New England': u'-290', u'Miami': u'+240'},
 {u'At Cleveland': u'+225', u'Baltimore': u'-265'},
 {u'At Pittsburgh': u'-175', u'Cincinnati': u'+155'},
 {u'At Washington': u'-150', u'Dallas': u'+130'},
 {u'At NY Giants': u'-215', u'New Orleans': u'+180'},
 {u'At Carolina': u'-900', u'San Francisco': u'+600'},
 {u'At Arizona': u'-330', u'Tampa Bay': u'+270'},
 {u'At Los Angeles': u'+250', u'Seattle': u'-300'},
 {u'At Denver': u'-275', u'Indianapolis': u'+235'},
 {u'At Oakland': u'-210', u'Atlanta': u'+180'},
 {u'At San Diego': u'-160', u'Jacksonville': u'+140'},
 {u'At Minnesota': u'+115', u'Green Bay': u'-135'}]
```

Comment: No worries, you are actually probably better of storing tuples so you will know the order, that or use something like `{"at": {"team":u'At Detroit',"spread":u'-255'}, "away: {"team": "u'Tennessee': "spread":u'+215'}}`